# What is the rationale behind the addresses of these local variables?

Tags: c, local-variables, stack-frame

I was playing around and looking at local variables in memory. To my surprise I don't understand why the addresses are what they are.

Here is the sample program

```
 int main() {
   int my_array[30]; 
   int a = 10; 
   int b = 11; 
   char h = 'A'; 
   char temp_array[10];
   int c = 12; 
 }
```

I expected the stack frame to be all of those variables in order.
In GDB printing out the memory addresses shows this is not the case!

```
(gdb) print &my_array
$4 = (int (*)[30]) 0x7fffffffde10
(gdb) print &a
$5 = (int *) 0x7fffffffde04
(gdb) print &b
$6 = (int *) 0x7fffffffde08
(gdb) print &h
$7 = 0x7fffffffde03 '/' <repeats 13 times>
(gdb) print &temp_array
$8 = (char (*)[10]) 0x7fffffffde90
(gdb) print &c
$9 = (int *) 0x7fffffffde0c
```

Based on these memory addresses, the stack frame is actually:

```
temp_array <--- Highest memory address
---------
my_array
---------
c
---------
b
---------
a
---------
h    <---- Lowest memory address
```

Why is this the case? I'm assuming my compiler(gcc) is arranging it this way for a reason, can someone tell me why? Thank you.
Edit: Could it be for byte alignment or something? Buffers go first, then integers, then characters, that being said then why does it go CBA instead of ABC?

Comment: If you overflow the top of the arrays, you probably do less damage if they are at the top of pile. If they were in order of declaration, overwriting the end of an array could affect scalar variables.  It is less likely as shown. (But you might overwrite function return addresses, etc).

Comment: I think it means you have to under flow your arrays, using negative subscripts. I’m not aware of options for helping you do stack smashing, but I’ve not looked for them either.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I appreciate it, I just tried compiling without stack protection and got the expected results. I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this the case?

The compiler is free to lay out the stack frame as it sees fit. This layout can change from version to version, from compiler to compiler, and with different optimization levels.

To know *precisely* why this particular layout was chosen, you'll have to step through GCC as it performs the layout.

In general, GCC may try to minimize holes / padding between variables (it annoys end-users when their programs run out of stack). That would explain why all the `int` variables got allocated together -- they have the same alignment requirement and can be allocated one after another with no gaps.